# Why My question over here considered as off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted this question over [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68571/why-cant-you-use-your-cellphone-on-an-airplane) , It was currently closed as off topic, I posted this question in order to know the impacts/effects related to physics while we using the mobile phones inside airplanes, so i choosed physics.se and posted it over here, Can anyone explain why my question is off topic here, as it basically covers about the physical effects while using phones inside airplanes?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [In the end this is a question about policy and technology not about physics as such](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68571/why-cant-you-use-your-cellphone-on-an-airplane#comment138625_68571)

The answer to this question is partly electronics and partly bureaucracy. A pure physics answer would just be able to say "there's a possibility of interference"; there's not much more we can give here. Explaining the interference would be more of an electronics issue again.

And all of this would require a deep understanding of how the plane communication systems and sensors work. That's engineering, really.

Basically, it's not something that can be adequately answered here. If you look at the current answer, there's almost no physics involved.

I suggest you have a look at [this page and the references therein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft)

Comment: i would like to migrate my question to electronics.se,what i need to do for migration

Comment: @Lonelybaby you ask a moderator :) I'm not entirely sure if electronics.se will accept it, though. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: @Lonelybaby sorry, I asked and it's apparently borderline off topic there too. (Also, it's already been addressed on skeptics.se).

Comment: but the skeptics.se doesnt provide the relevant answer :(,now where i can get answers its bad and highly disappointed ...,

Comment: @lonely put a bounty on it. Or improve it. (http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)